# SQL convert to all caps in a case when

Tags: sql

I am writing some sql to standardize country names. I have written the following:

```
SELECT
CASE Country
WHEN 'USA' THEN 'UNITED STATES'
WHEN 'US' THEN 'UNITED STATES'
WHEN 'CAN' THEN 'CANADA'
WHEN 'CA' THEN 'CANADA'
WHEN 'AU' THEN 'AUSTRALIA'
WHEN 'AUS' THEN 'AUSTRALIA'
ELSE Country
END AS Country_Standard  
FROM TABLE1
```

I would like to add some logic that would say, if length of string in country is greater than or equal to 4 then capitalize the whole string. Could that be added to a `CASE WHEN` clause? The below code does not work as an additional clause, but would some variant be possible?

```
WHEN LEN() >= 4 THEN UPPER()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an argument to `UPPER()`.  So, you should use the other form of the `CASE`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Country IN ('USA', 'US') THEN 'UNITED STATES'
             WHEN Country IN ('CAN', 'CA') THEN 'CANADA'
             WHEN Country IN ('AUS', 'AU') THEN 'AUSTRALIA'
             WHEN LEN(Country) > 4 THEN UPPER(Country)
             ELSE Country
        END) AS Country_Standard
```